# Cucumber : Is it possible to achieve parallel execution of cucumber scenarios with features files executed synchronously

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, parallel-execution

I have multiple feature files which are to be executed synchronously along with that I would like to have parallel execution of scenarios mentioned in these feature files.
Any suggestions/feedback is really appreciated.

Tried parallel execution as mentioned in [Cucumber Documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/?lang=java) and the scenarios from all feature files were executed parallely.

Comment: What test engine are you using (i.e. JUnit 4)? What have you tried and what was the outcome? If you already tried the suggestions in the linked documentation, why do you want to do achieve the same differently? Why not stick to the suggested approach?

Comment: @hfontanez, thanks for your reply. Earlier, I was using Junit but now I am using TestNG to achieve my particular case. Now, I am maintaining multiple runner classes pointing to different feature files, as a result the feature files get executed synchronously and with TestNG able to execute scenarios parallelly within the feature files.